# Rails' `average` method doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, average

According to [wikibooks.org](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations#Average) and [rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average), this should be working:

```
Table.average(:score, :conditions => ['user_id=?', 1])
```

But it's not. Why? When I'm doing above, my console says:

```
SELECT AVG("table"."score") FROM "table"
```

No conditions at all.

Eventually, I did what I want like this:

```
Table.where('user_id=?', 1).average(:score)
```

But I'm still confused.

Comment: Pavan, pls .. tell me where can i find those kind of informations what methods working in each version of Rails. It would help me in the future.

Comment: Without reading the docs or anything, the `user_` in `user_id` seems odd, or do you have a `user belongs_to user` in place? `id` or `user.ud` seems the more realistic choice for me.

Comment: i'm searching user_id in table calld "table" in this example. I wanted to generate this SQL : SELECT AVG("table"."score") FROM "table" WHERE (user_id='3')

Comment: I think you should avoid naming a table "table" ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: I wonder how you get this `SELECT AVG("table"."score") FROM "table"` with this `User.average(:score, :conditions => ['user_id=?', 1])` in the console. It should be like this `SELECT AVG("users"."score") FROM "users"`

Comment: I'm verry sorry .. I wrote my post bad (i corrected just now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use so-called `finders api` which has been [deprecated](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-active-record) starting from Rails 4.0 and has been moved to a separate gem [activerecord-deprecated-finders](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders) to ease migration from older versions. `Finders api` has been [completely removed](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders#active-record-deprecated-finders) starting from Rails 4.1.

In light of the above your solution

```
User.where(user_id: 1).average(:score)
```

is correct.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you!